# Persisting a DataFrame across requests within a Django

Tags: python, django, dataframe, django-views

I am in the process of re-writing a conceptual Project Management app from Jupyter notebook into a Django app (for context: to be compiled into a windows exe, and accessed over localhost).

The main Model is `Event` which has the usual attributes. However, the `Event`  has a timeseries-indexed DataFrame (~2,000 rows; 50 columns) that can get modified depending on any updates that the user might make during their session. For example:

- changing the start or end date
- adding or removing a department (which are columns)

Is this something that should/could be added to `request.session['myDataFrame']`?

Comment: Keeping a file in session does not seem to be a very good idea